# Scheduled task runs twice after DST

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler, windows-server-2019

We have a process in Task Scheduler that runs at 8:10am on certain days of the month. This has worked fine for years. We u/ged to Server 2019. Then, after this year's DST switch over and server upgrade, this task runs at 8:10am and 9:10am. Per [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/549367/task-scheduler-ran-a-task-twice) question, I've restarted the server and recreated the task. Same issue.

Server : Windows 2019 Datacenter

The task still runs twice, scheduled time and exactly 1 hour later.

What are the next steps to try? Is this a regression?

Comment: I think you’re missing something here. From what I can tell I think the server has two different tasks. You even recreated it with the same problems. But did you delete or disable it and just wait out the next scheduled time to see if only 1 task runs?

Comment: Disabled the task, still ran.

Comment: Yes, but did one task run or did two tasks run? What time did it run? If you disabled the task, I expect that only one execution took place, meaning there is still another task in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the exact same issue on server 2016 in our environment. I've found the only solution is to delete the job and recreate it. It's not a good solution though as it can start occurring again shortly after.

If anyone has a real fix, please advise.